Realms sync double level inheritance error
I have a .net maui (so we’re talking C# / .net) project in which I want to implement mongodb atlas device sync: my data model is composed by two classes (LockerEntry and LockerItemEntry) that inherits from a common parent (DbEntry) that inherits from RealmObject (pretty straightforward).
My realm app (the one created from the web mongo dashboard) has the developer mode on, because I want schema and db collection to be generated from my data model.
What I’m experiencing is that, when running my .net maui app, DbEntry collection and schema are created just fine (in fact, this is unwanted, but i’ve already figured out that annotating the class with Realms.Ignored attribute will prevent it), whereas LockerEntry and LockerItemEntry are not, and realm initialization throws an error saying “The class LockerEntry is not in the limited set of classes for this realm (Parameter ‘T’)”
Here a snippet of LockerEntry (one of the two classes to be synced) and DbEntry (the parent class):
public class LockerEntry : DbEntry
{
    public string? Name {  get; set; }
    
    public override void FromPersisted(object persistedObject)
    {
        Locker locker = (Locker)persistedObject;

        Id = locker.Id;

        Name = EncryptionHelper.EncryptString(DependencyHelper.DataModel.PassKey, locker.Name);
    }
}

public abstract class DbEntry : RealmObject, IDbEntry
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [SQLitePrimaryKey]
    [MapTo("_id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public abstract void FromPersisted(object persistedObject);
}

and to initialize the realm I use this code:
public async Task InitRealmAsync()
{
    RealmsApp realmsApp = RealmsApp.Create(new AppConfiguration("<my_app>")
    {
        BaseFilePath = DirectoryHelper.DBFolder
    });

    await realmsApp.LogInAsync(Credentials.ApiKey("<my_key>"));

    FlexibleSyncConfiguration config = new(realmsApp.CurrentUser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException())
    {
        PopulateInitialSubscriptions = (realm) =>
        {
            var lockerEntries = realm.All<LockerEntry>();
            var lockerItemEntries = realm.All<LockerItemEntry>();

            realm.Subscriptions.Add(lockerEntries);
            realm.Subscriptions.Add(lockerItemEntries);
        }
    };

    realm = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync(config);

    var lockerEntries = realm.All<LockerEntry>();
    var lockerItemEntries = realm.All<LockerItemEntry>();
}

Making LockerEntry and LockerItemEntry inherit directly from RealmObject instead of DbEntry and then RealmObject would work, but then I should duplicate the code contained in DbEntry parent class, and I’d rather not do that…
Would you please provide some suggestions?
